# Install wordpress local site with Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I downloaded a github folder with a wordpress site, after the unzip the weight of it is about 1,8 gb. 
Inside the master folder I've 9 folders, two of them named: 
1: wp-content 
2: wp-includes

I already created the docker-compose.yml file and the code inside it is this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The lines up above are necessary only for install wordpress.
Now my question is, what could I do to install and launch the complete site that i downloaded ?

The entire process must be done with docker, install and launch the site.

Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the volume mount points which contains the existing app source code and the db files and the script to do db update.
wordpress section in docker-compose

```
   volumes:
      - ./codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com:/var/www/html
```

mysql section in docker-compose

```
volumes:
  - ./codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com.20170808-024302.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql.gz
  - ./migrate.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sql
```

This example uses nginx webserver
Ref : https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/migrate-wordpress-docker/